# Convert Days Int64 to Date

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timedelta

I need to convert the following dataframe (days) to a physical date.  When (days=0) this is the base year 01/01/1960.  Can you assist with converting the days column (literally days from 01/01/1960) back to a date?

```
df=pd.DataFrame([-730,-640,-549,457,-365,275,-184,-92,0,91,182,274,366],columns=['days'])
df['base_year']=datetime.date(1960,1,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In retrospect, MaxU's answer is better. The following might be useful for older Pandas versions.

There are several ways of doing this. One is using `datetime.timedelta` with list comprehension:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

>>> [pd.to_datetime('01/01/1960') + timedelta(d) for d in [-730,-640,-549,457,-365,275,-184,-92,0,91,182,274,366]]
[Timestamp('1958-01-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1958-04-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1958-07-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1961-04-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1959-01-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1960-10-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1959-07-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1959-10-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1960-01-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1960-04-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1960-07-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1960-10-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('1961-01-01 00:00:00')]
```

So you can use

```
>>> DataFrame([pd.to_datetime('01/01/1960') + timedelta(d) for d in [-730,-640,-549,457,-365,275,-184,-92,0,91,182,274,366]],columns=['days'])
    days
0   1958-01-01
1   1958-04-01
2   1958-07-01
3   1961-04-02
4   1959-01-01
5   1960-10-02
6   1959-07-01
7   1959-10-01
8   1960-01-01
9   1960-04-01
10  1960-07-01
11  1960-10-01
12  1961-01-01
```

Comment: Ami, if I already have this in a dataframe it is returning an error.  'year_quarter' is the days from '01/01/1960' the data type of "year_quarter' is int64.  quarterly_data['date']=pd.to_datetime('01/01/1960')+datetime.timedelta(days=quarterly_data['year_quarter'])

Comment: @Kyle In that case, you can use `df.days.apply(lambda d: timedelta(days=d) + pd.to_datetime('01/01/1960'))`, but MaxU's answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use relatively new feature (added in Pandas 0.20.0) - `origin` of [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
In [44]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['days'], origin='1960-01-01', unit='D')

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
    days       date
0   -730 1958-01-01
1   -640 1958-04-01
2   -549 1958-07-01
3    457 1961-04-02
4   -365 1959-01-01
5    275 1960-10-02
6   -184 1959-07-01
7    -92 1959-10-01
8      0 1960-01-01
9     91 1960-04-01
10   182 1960-07-01
11   274 1960-10-01
12   366 1961-01-01
```

from [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> **origin** : scalar, default is ‘unix’
>
> Define the reference date. The numeric values would be parsed as
> number of units (defined by unit) since this reference date.
>
> If ‘unix’ (or POSIX) time; origin is set to 1970-01-01. If ‘julian’,
> unit must be ‘D’, and origin is set to beginning of Julian Calendar.
>
> Julian day number 0 is assigned to the day starting at noon on January
>
> 1, 4713 BC. If Timestamp convertible, origin is set to Timestamp
> identified by origin.